# How to get messages via imap_tools excluding some UID?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imap

Test code:

```
fetch_criteria = AND(seen=False), AND(NOT(uid=['61','88']))
for message in mailbox.fetch(fetch_criteria, mark_seen=False, charset='utf8', limit=10):
    print(message.uid)
```

Server response:

> SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']

Please help me correctly create the conditions to exclude emails with UID 66 and 88

Answer (score 1):

```
from imap_tools import AND, NOT
mailbox.fetch(AND(NOT(uid=['39', '40'])))
mailbox.fetch(NOT(AND(uid=['39', '40'])))
```

Both works for me at [yandex, google, outlook, zimbra].

May be your server can not do this.

Error example at mail.ru: imap_tools.errors.MailboxSearchError: Response status "OK" expected, but "NO" received. Data: [b'[CANNOT] Unsupported search criterion: (UID 5,6)']

Lib author.

Comment: Большое спасибо Владимир за эту библиотеку! У меня эта проблема с gmail, решил обойти ее просто, при перебре почты сверяю UID, в условиях прописать так и не вышло. Не подскажете еще такой момент, msg.date_str     # str: original date - 'Tue, 03 Jan 2017 22:26:59 +0500' это дата отправки или получения сервером письма?

Comment: Пожалуйста. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.1 
*Здесь лучше писать на английском.